# Volttron Central (VC): How to add "Register platform" button?

Tags: volttron

After successfully creating VC. According to the documentation: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/4.1/devguides/walkthroughs/VOLTTRON-Central-Demo.html#starting-the-demo
by selecting the "platforms" tab I can register new platform by pressing the button.

Unfortunately, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae9e1.png)  is how my screen look like when I press the "platforms" tab.

Please how to add the button?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The platforms now auto register when the external VOLTTRON Central Platform connects with VOLTTRON Central